# How to apply pagination on mat-table

Tags: angular

i want to apply pagination on mat-table data coming from API but showing  data always empty or null,   dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.ListOfReceivedPurchaseOrder); is this a right way to map data into MatTableDataSource?

```html
<section style="margin-top: 10px;">
    <table mat-table [dataSource]="dataSource" class="table table-striped">

      <!-- Position Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Id">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>ID</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Id}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Name Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ExpectedTime">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Expected Time </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ExpectedTime}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="ReceivedTime">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Received Time </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.ReceivedTime}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <!-- Weight Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Status">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Status</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element"> {{element.Status}} </td>
      </ng-container>

      <!-- Symbol Column -->
      <ng-container matColumnDef="VendorName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vendor Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.VendorName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="VendorContact">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Vendor Contact</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.Contact}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="SkuGroupName">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>Sku Group Name</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">{{element.SkuGroupName}} </td>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container matColumnDef="Edit">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef> Edit</th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let element">
          <button mat-raised-button color="primary" (click)="openDialog(element.Id)">Detail</button>
        </td>
      </ng-container>
      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="ReceivedPO"></tr>
      <tr mat-row *matRowDef="let row; columns: ReceivedPO;"></tr>
    </table>
    <mat-paginator [pageSizeOptions]="[5, 10, 20]"  showFirstLastButtons></mat-paginator>
  </section>
```

Comment: @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
   ListOfReceivedPurchaseOrder = [];
   dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.ListOfReceivedPurchaseOrder);

Comment: Can you provide the dataSource array?

Comment: thank you it work successfully after doing little changes, but if i use two <mat-paginator> on same page only one paginator work at a time

Comment: @ViewChild(MatPaginator) paginator: MatPaginator;
  dataSource=new MatTableDataSource(this.ListOfReceivedPurchaseOrder);
  dataSourcePPO=new MatTableDataSource(this.ListOfPendingPurchaseOrder);

Comment: This is another feature. Please provide more code so we are able to reproduce the problem if you want help.